# create database permission denied in database ‘master'-sql 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

So I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on windows 7 machine.I was able to login using my windows authentication.Now when I try to create a new database it gives me this error saying "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database ‘master'".I have tried so many links related to this issue but still it is failing.These are the options that I tried:

1) Went to SQL Server Configuration Manager and then changed the parameters in the advanced tab by adding -m.It still did not help me.When I add this parameter and try to login again using windows authentication it gives me a message saying "Only one administrator can login as it is in single user mode".

2) While Installation I am sure that I added the current user under sysadmin role. I also made sure that the "Mixed mode authentication" is selected and then gave a password for the user "sa".Now when I try to use that password it says "Failed login for user sa".

3) When I login with windows authentication and then check the login mode by following this:

right click on main instance name-->Properties-->Security,it shows that only windows authentication mode is selected.But I am very much sure that I selected the "Mixed mode authentication".Not sure why it is showing it in this way.

4) I also tried to modify the password for sa but the current user has no permissions.I am not able to perform any operation with this user.

I know there are different links for this issue.But I tried all the options that were mentioned in those links but still it is giving me a problem.I have been trying to resolve this issue from a very long time.Could anyone suggest what I am missing here.

Comment: Try to run SQL Server in single user mode: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/07/12/disaster-recovery-what-to-do-when-the-sa-account-password-is-lost-in-sql-server-2005.aspx

Comment: Yeah I did follow that link after I login with the windows authentication and then try to run the command "EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember 'CONTOSO\Buck', 'sysadmin';
GO"  I get the following error "Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_addsrvrolemember, Line 29
User does not have permission to perform this action."

Comment: Also I get the following error when I add the "-m;" parameter in the instance and then try to login:  "Login failed for user.Reason:server is in single user mode.Only one administrator can connect at this time."  I am using SQL server management studio.

Comment: Do not login to SSMS normaly, cancel login and login just one query. See http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2011/12/02/cannot-login-to-sql-server-using-administrator-account.aspx

Comment: Or try this one http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have now installed SQL server 2012 and it serves the purpose for me now.Would try working on SQL 2008 R2 again.Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!  I had the same problem.  I figured it out based on info from the article and the comments from the first commentor in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/07/12/disaster-recovery-what-to-do-when-the-sa-account-password-is-lost-in-sql-server-2005.aspx) link.

I'll copy the author's steps with the necessary modifications in bold:

> 1. Open the Configuration Manager tool from the "SQL Server 2005| Configuration" menu
> 2. Stop the SQL Server Instance you need to recover **(both SQL Server AND SQL Server Agent.  Once in single user mode, if not stoped, the agent will tie up the connection, preventing you from using it with sqlcmd.exe).**
> 3. In SQL Configuration Manager, click on SQL Server Services on the left, then right click on SQL Server on the right, navigate to the “Advanced” tab (or "Startup Parameters for more recent versions of SQL), and in the Properties text box add “–m” to the end of the list in the “Startup parameters” option.
> 4. Click the “OK” button and restart the SQL Server Instance **(just SQL Server.  Do not restart the SQL Server Agent just yet.)**   NOTE: make sure there is no space between “;” and “-m”, the registry
>      parameter parser is sensitive to such typos. You should see an entry
>      in the SQL Server ERRORLOG file that says “SQL Server started in
>      single-user mode.”
> 5. After the SQL Server Instance starts in single-user mode, the Windows Administrator account is able to connect to SQL Server using
>      the sqlcmd utility **(it is probably here, or someplace very similar:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE)** using Windows authentication. You can use
>      Transact-SQL commands such as "sp_addsrvrolemember" to add an existing
>      login (or a newly created one) to the sysadmin server role. The
>      following example adds the account "Buck" in the "CONTOSO" domain to
>      the SQL Server "sysadmin" role:   EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember
>      'CONTOSO\Buck', 'sysadmin'; GO
> 6. **Restart/Start SQL Server Agent, back in the SQL Server Configuration Manager.**

Comment: I needed to it without the ;.  It was just "-m", without the quotes.  I found a good link for setting up Single User Mode for Windows 10 and SQL 2014+ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345416.aspx